# How does cfexchangeconnection support the % symbol?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

With Coldfusion 9, we experience an error when the password used in a call to cfexchangeconnection contains a % symbol.

The error is:

```
Could not log in to the Exchange server.

Verify server name, username, and password.
```

The username and passwords are not suspect as we can log into the system with CFLDAP just fine.  Further, if we change the password to one that does not have the percent sign the cfexchangeconnection works just fine.

How does cfexchangeconnection support the % symbol?

Comment: I would say that this is not by design, and is just a bug in CF. Indeed, even if it IS by design, it's poor design and wouls still qualify as a bug. You should probably raise it with Adobe: https://bugbase.adobe.com

Comment: Yeah, it may well be a bug. This is a shot in the dark, but any change if you try escaping the character ie For example `%25` or possibly `\%` instead of just `%`?

Comment: Bananas! @Leigh I had thought about trying that and started to look for the character code and got distracted.  %25 does work.  Still rather buggy I would say. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed. I would go ahead and submit a bug report. In the meantime, I guess the workaround is to use something like `URLEncodedFormat(thePassword)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From the comments)

This is a shot in the dark, but any change if you try escaping the character ie For example `%25` (ie url encoding) or possibly `\%` instead of just `%`?

I would go ahead and submit a bug report as Adam suggested. In the meantime, I guess the workaround is to use something like `URLEncodedFormat(thePassword)` ?

Comment: Thanks! Fascinatingly, when there are spaces and ampersands in the password you can send them plainly or through URLEncodedFormat and get a successful result.

Comment: Now that is weird... Perhaps they just forgotten about the `%` ..?

Comment: (.. or forgot to mention special cases in the documentation).